# Looking for Tor GUI tool like TorK

Tags: linux, gui, tor

I really appreciate the "Change Identity", "Drag to build circuit", and "Choose where you from..." feature in TorK, others (e.g. Vidalia or Torbutton) are missing these features.

But Tork is based on Qt3 and stopped update for years, is there any alternatives to it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I have never heard of any of those things? Is it a circuit designing tools?

Comment: @ppumkin no, just a Tor GUI.